# Using user-id in google analytics to figure out the user flow

Tags: google-analytics

What I am after is to know the flow of particular users in my app in Users Flow or Behavior Flow.

I've added the User-ID to be tracked and can see different user ids under Overview -> User Explorer. However, that seems to be the only place where I can associate the User Id with different behavior.
[image]

Under Users Flow or Behavior Flow I cannot seem to be able to filter using the user-id, so what I end up seeing is how each session flows but what I am after is the flow of a particular user who had multiple sessions.
[image]

Can it be done?

Or can I at least get a session id of a user and track that?